# YII2 Active Record Query Get Records Weekly

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to get records per week assuming Monday as first day of the week according to the `date_received` column.

What should be the equivalent active record query for this raw query?

```
$week = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM dts_document WHERE date_received > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)');
```

I tried the following but it returns the entire record.

```
$week = DtsDocument::find()->where(['>','date_received', 'DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'])->count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `DATE_SUB` part with [yii\db\Expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-expression.html) to prevent quoting:

```
use yii\db\Expression;

...

$week = DtsDocument::find()
    ->where(['>', 'date_received', new Expression('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')])
    ->count();
```